# Not showing server option in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Not getting "Server" Menu option when "Window --> Preferences" is opened in Eclipse IDE,Please let me know how to get that menu option enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Java EE package?  That is [required](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) for server tools.